# Why does BalloonTipTitle appear twice in toast notification on Windows 10 Anniversary (1607)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

*Just noticed the title gets shown top and bottom of the toast now in a C# application I'm building. Anyone else see the same thing? In pre-anniversary Windows 10, the BalloonTipTitle only appeared in the top portion of the toast.
Not a big deal, but it looks silly.
I can't post pictures yet, but if I get any responses I'll upload pre and post-anniversary pictures of the toast behavior.*

I think I'm getting downvoted because it wasn't really a question. So I'll rephrase:

Windows 10 Anniversary is putting the *BalloonTipTitle* at the top, and ***assembly: AssemblyTitle*** from *AssemblyInfo.cs* at the bottom of the toast.

What's the best way to manage this across different versions of Windows 10 and 7? I want my user to know my app caused the toast, but I don't want to duplicate information.

Here's some quick code in a Windows Forms Application that shows what I mean. If you change the BalloonTipTitle to match your solution name, you'll see the redundant title:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        NotifyIcon myNotifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        myNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Warning;
        myNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "This is a test toast";
        myNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Toast Title";
        myNotifyIcon.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        myNotifyIcon.Visible = true;
        myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000);

        ContextMenuStrip contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem menuItemExit = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        menuItemExit.Text = "Exit";
        contextMenu.Items.Add(menuItemExit);
        menuItemExit.Click += delegate { myNotifyIcon.Visible = false; Application.Exit(); };

        myNotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenu;

        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Interval = 20000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
        myTimer.Elapsed += delegate { myNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(10000); };

        Application.Run();
    }
```

Comment: How about some code? The way it sounds right now, it's an OS issue, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to check the CurrentBuild registry key after checking for Windows 10. Anything greater than or equal to build 14393 (Anniversary), and I'll leave out the BalloonTipTitle

```
    bool AppNameInBaloon = false;

    string BuildString = ReadHKLMValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "CurrentBuild");

    int CurrentBuild;

    bool WasParsed = Int32.TryParse(BuildString, out CurrentBuild);

    if (WasParsed)
    {
        if (CurrentBuild >= 14393)
        {
            AppNameInBaloon = true;
        }
    }


private static string ReadHKLMValue(string regPath, string value)
    {
        RegistryKey localKey;

        if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        {
            localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        }
        else
        {
            localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
        }

        string keyValue;

        try
        {
            keyValue = localKey.OpenSubKey(regPath).GetValue(value).ToString();
            return keyValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            keyValue = "";
        }

        return keyValue;
    }
```